# Проблема с откладкой в MVS

Tags: visual-studio

В MVS я создал cpp, header и cpp.В первом cpp функция main,во втором cpp вспомогательные функции, а в header все переменные и названия функций (вспомогательных). Я нажимаю F10 и как только дохожу до функции, функция срабатывает, только я не вижу процесс работы функции, хотя есть результат. Как посмотреть на работу функций в режиме откладки? Функции статические, а подключены с помощью extern.

Comment: для входы внутри нужно использовать F11

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ.